# kotlin function is not recognized in java

Tags: java, kotlin

I need to transform this and some other code made in kotlin to java, but it is not working. Here is one of them.

BackgroundActivity.kt (this I need to transform to java):

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
  override fun surfaceChanged(holder: SurfaceHolder, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
    RtpService.setView(surfaceView)
    RtpService.startPreview()
  }
```

This function is inside a kotlin class, that I will keep
RtpService.kt

```
package com.wifi.service.backgroundexample

import android.app.Notification
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.os.IBinder
import android.util.Log
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import com.wifi.rtplibrary.base.Camera2Base
import com.wifi.rtplibrary.rtmp.RtmpCamera2
import com.wifi.rtplibrary.rtsp.RtspCamera2
import com.wifi.rtplibrary.view.OpenGlView
import com.wifi.service.R


/**
 * Basic RTMP/RTSP service streaming implementation with camera2
 */
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
class RtpService : Service() {

  private var endpoint: String? = null

  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    Log.e(TAG, "RTP service create")
    notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
      val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, channelId, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
      notificationManager?.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
    keepAliveTrick()
  }

  private fun keepAliveTrick() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
      val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
          .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_settings_24_branco)
          .setSilent(true)
          .setOngoing(false)
          //.setContentTitle("")
          .build()
      startForeground(1, notification)
    } else {
      startForeground(1, Notification())
    }
  }

  override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? {
    return null
  }

  override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    Log.e(TAG, "RTP service started")
    endpoint = intent?.extras?.getString("endpoint")
    if (endpoint != null) {
      prepareStreamRtp()
      startStreamRtp(endpoint!!)
    }
    return START_STICKY
  }

  companion object {
    private const val TAG = "RtpService"
    //private const val channelId = "rtpStreamChannel"
    private const val channelId = "Android"
    private const val notifyId = 123456
    private var notificationManager: NotificationManager? = null
    private var camera2Base: Camera2Base? = null
    private var openGlView: OpenGlView? = null
    private var contextApp: Context? = null

    fun setView(openGlView: OpenGlView) {
      this.openGlView = openGlView
      camera2Base?.replaceView(openGlView)
    }

    fun setView(context: Context) {
      contextApp = context
      this.openGlView = null
      camera2Base?.replaceView(context)
    }

    fun startPreview() {
      camera2Base?.startPreview()
    }

    fun init(context: Context) {
      contextApp = context
      if (camera2Base == null) camera2Base = RtmpCamera2(context, true, connectCheckerRtp)
    }

    fun stopStream() {
      if (camera2Base != null) {
        if (camera2Base!!.isStreaming) camera2Base!!.stopStream()
      }
    }

    fun stopPreview() {
      if (camera2Base != null) {
        if (camera2Base!!.isOnPreview) camera2Base!!.stopPreview()
      }
    }


    private val connectCheckerRtp = object : ConnectCheckerRtp {
      override fun onConnectionStartedRtp(rtpUrl: String) {
        //showNotification("Stream connection started")
      }

      override fun onConnectionSuccessRtp() {
        //showNotification("Stream started")
        Log.e(TAG, "RTP service destroy")
      }

      override fun onNewBitrateRtp(bitrate: Long) {

      }

      override fun onConnectionFailedRtp(reason: String) {
        //showNotification("Stream connection failed")
        Log.e(TAG, "RTP service destroy")
      }

      override fun onDisconnectRtp() {
        //showNotification("Stream stopped")
      }

      override fun onAuthErrorRtp() {
        //showNotification("Stream auth error")
      }

      override fun onAuthSuccessRtp() {
        //showNotification("Stream auth success")
      }
    }

    private fun showNotification(text: String) {
      contextApp?.let {
        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(it, channelId)
            //.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_settings_24_branco)
            .setContentTitle("RTP Stream")
            .setSilent(true)
            .setOngoing(false)
            .setContentText(text).build()
        notificationManager?.notify(notifyId, notification)
      }
    }
  }

  override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    Log.e(TAG, "RTP service destroy")
    stopStream()
  }

  private fun prepareStreamRtp() {
    stopStream()
    stopPreview()
    if (endpoint!!.startsWith("rtmp")) {
      camera2Base = if (openGlView == null) {
        RtmpCamera2(baseContext, true, connectCheckerRtp)
      } else {
        RtmpCamera2(openGlView, connectCheckerRtp)
      }
    } else {
      camera2Base = if (openGlView == null) {
        RtspCamera2(baseContext, true, connectCheckerRtp)
      } else {
        RtspCamera2(openGlView, connectCheckerRtp)
      }
    }
  }

  private fun startStreamRtp(endpoint: String) {
    if (!camera2Base!!.isStreaming) {
      if (camera2Base!!.prepareVideo() && camera2Base!!.prepareAudio()) {
        camera2Base!!.startStream(endpoint)
      }
    } else {
      //showNotification("You are already streaming :(")
    }
  }
}
```

I tried this with java:

JavaVersion.java

```
RtpService rtpService = new RtpService();
rtpService.init(this);
```

init is not recognized, I don't work well with kotlin yet

Comment: Please show the `RtpService` full code

Comment: The complete code follows above

Comment: You should not be putting all that stuff in a companion object in the first place. Views should not be stored in static variables in Java, or in objects/top level properties in Kotlin. You're leaking them outside their scope.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int p1, int p2, int p3) {
        Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter(holder, "holder");
        RtpService.setView(surfaceView);
        RtpService.startPreview();
    }

public void setView(OpenGlView openGlView) {
        this.openGlView = openGlView;
        camera2Base.replaceView(openGlView);
    }
```